# Random number generator with range and higher probability for bigger numbers in java

Tags: java, random

I want to make a method in java where I can input the maximum and minimum numbers and it will give me a random number, but with a higher chance of a bigger number than a smaller one. How would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `higher`?  Can you be specific on how much higher you want it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, as it is about 'gimme the codes'.

Comment: I would like it to be 10% more likely to have an answer over ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots of ways to do this depending on what you mean by higher.  You can skew your distribution with a function.

```
int num = (int) (func(Math.random()) * (max - min)) + min;
```

Your `func` could be `Math.sqrt` or `Math.pow(x, n)` where `n < 1` to favour higher numbers.

> I would like it to be 10% more likely to have an answer over ten.

If this is your requirement, you actually have two distributions.

```
 private static final Random rand = new Random();
 public static int randBetween(int min, int max) {
       return rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
 }


 int next = rand.nextInt(100) < 10 ? // a 10% chance
            randBetween(10, max) : // random of at least 10
            randBetween(min, max); // otherwise any number.
```

Comment: @personMMIV Updated based on your comment.

Comment: @personMMIV If you want to learn more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling